# JPanel appearing to be two times bigger than set resolution

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I must say I tried everything and I can't understand what's wrong with my code.
In my `SIView` class I create `MainFrame` which extends `JFrame` with specified resolution (let's say X,Y).
Then I create `gamePanel` which extends `JPanel` whith the same resolution as `MainFrame`, and add it to `MainFrame`. The problem is that effective resolution of the panel is twice as big (x*2, y*2). It's like the panel is being streched to be twice as big.

Frame will display only a quarter (upper left quarter) of the panel either with `pack()` or mannualy setting the size, unless I set it to double the resolution in which case It's ok, but that's not a proper way to do that(When calculating positions in the game I have to double everything or divide it by 2 to keep proper proportions). I even tried different Layout managers wthout any succes.

Here's the code of the main view class:

```
public class SIView implements Runnable {

private final MainFrame mainFrame;
private final GamePanel gamePanel;

public SIView(BlockingQueue<SIEvent> eventQueue) {
    this.eventsQueue = eventQueue;
    mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    gamePanel = new GamePanel();

    gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
    // mainFrame.pack();



@Override
public void run() {
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void init() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);

}
  //some code not related

}
```

the frame class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6513420589842315661L;

public MainFrame() {
    setTitle("Space Intruders");
    setSize(new Dimension(SIParams.RES_X, SIParams.RES_Y));
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

panel class:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8112087715257989968L;

private final PlayerShipView playerShip;
private final ArrayList<SmallEnemyShipView> smallEnemyShip;
private final ArrayList<LightMissleView> lightMissle;

public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIParams.RES_X, SIParams.RES_Y));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(SIParams.RES_X, SIParams.RES_Y));
    setBounds(0, 0, SIParams.RES_X, SIParams.RES_Y);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    // TODO
    playerShip = new PlayerShipView();
    smallEnemyShip = new ArrayList<SmallEnemyShipView>();
    lightMissle = new ArrayList<LightMissleView>();
    this.add(playerShip);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}

//some code not related
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components. 3) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: As an aside.  That slew of words contains no '?'.  Do you have a question?

Comment: To clear it up, what happens if you put an hardcoded number in the parameters, for example the frame 100,100 and the panel 50*50? If it still doubles the parameters the panel would be the same size then, does this happen or does it then set correctly. If so it might be the SIParams that's doing something strange.

Comment: How big is `PlayerShipView`?

Comment: What happens if you don't set the size of your frame and uncomment the line "mainFrame.pack();" ?

Comment: @adenoyelle I've already tried that, no result

Comment: @MadProgrammer Player ship view is a class extending JComponent with position info and paintcomponent method

Comment: @Skillcoil If i mannualy set frame to 100x100 and panel to 50x50 then it looks ok, but that implies problems with position resolution becouse panel is streched not expanded.

Comment: Then could you post something about the SIParams? Where does it come from, what are the values inside? Try and backtrace and see what and how changes that. If that's correct, then it might point to what makes the parameters *2 for the panel.

Comment: @Skillcoil SIParams is a class with public static final parameters like resolution etc. currently RES_X is 400 and RES_Y is 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `LayoutManager` and properly override `getPreferredSize()` in `GamePanel`, the code seems to work as expected:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jfree.ui.OverlayLayout;

public class SIView implements Runnable {

    public static interface SIParams {

        int RES_X = 500;
        int RES_Y = 400;
    }

    public static class GamePanel extends JPanel {
        public GamePanel() {
            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            setLayout(new OverlayLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SIParams.RES_X, SIParams.RES_Y);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        // some code not related
    }

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainFrame = createMainFrame();
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JFrame createMainFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Space Intruders");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return frame;
    }

    public void init() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);

    }

    // some code not related

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SIView().init();
    }

}
```

I also dropped the `MainFrame` class since it is not needed to extend `JFrame` in this context.

Comment: Unfortunately effect is the same, I still can place my ship below the frame while staying inside RES_Y and RES_X bounds. I might have not explain this enough. Frame size is perfect, it's the panel that excedes frame bounds. And yes i'm sure that it's not the problem with the ship movement, because i'm displaying its position, and it stays within given values.

Comment: It's behaves like the representation of pixel on the panel is not 1x1 but 2x2.

Comment: @MichałMuniuMajczak _And yes i'm sure that it's not the problem with the ship movement_ I actually think that your problem lies in what you are not showing us. What I am actually sure is that the code I have provided above has no issue. Consider updating your code with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). The problem may just be in your `LayoutManager` or in your `paintComponent`. With the information you have provided so far, nobody will be able to help you more.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I'll be working on it, and maybe post the way to solve this...

Comment: Ok, i just saw, that you're using     import org.jfree.ui.OverlayLayout; and i'm only using import javax.swing.OverlayLayout; Can this be the problem?

Comment: @MichałMuniuMajczak No because I don't have any child component in that container. The problem comes most likely from the way you paint your objects. I can only repeat myself and encourage you to update your post with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I can almost guarantee you that I will find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved everything :D But I must say I feel stupid. The problem was with painting my components, in `paintcomponent()` method I painted rectangle on a relative position while changing component position also relatively. That gave the effect of 2xtimes movement etc. because while the component was moving the rectangle was moving inside of it too. I guess I have a lot to learn about Swing ;) Sorry for all this trouble ;)

PS. I didn't have to change anything in Panel/Frame classes except for using `pack()` method after everything.